# PHP foreach multi array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, foreach

I use the https://github.com/humanmade/Custom-Meta-Boxes/ to make this custom repeatable custom fields to wordpress. The given arrays are like this

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [photoset-caption] => Array
                (
                    [cmb-field-0] => Caption1
                    [cmb-field-1] => Caption2
                    [cmb-field-2] => Caption3
                    [cmb-field-3] => Caption4
                )

            [photoset-image] => Array
                (
                    [cmb-field-0] => 17
                    [cmb-field-1] => 16
                    [cmb-field-2] => 15
                    [cmb-field-3] => 14
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [photoset-caption] => Array
                (
                    [cmb-field-0] => Caption1
                    [cmb-field-1] => Caption2
                    [cmb-field-2] => Caption3
                    [cmb-field-3] => Caption4
                )

            [photoset-image] => Array
                (
                    [cmb-field-0] => 17
                    [cmb-field-1] => 16
                    [cmb-field-2] => 15
                    [cmb-field-3] => 14
                )

        )

)
```

The loop it try to make is this.

```
 // get the custom fields for this post
    $photoset = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'photoset_group_fields', false ); 

        echo '<div class="photoset">';
        echo '<div class="photoset-row">';

        foreach($photoset as $photosetloop){
        echo '<figure class="photoset-item">';
        echo '<div>' . wp_get_attachment_image($photosetloop['photoset-image'], 'large' ) . '</div>';
        echo '<figcaption>' . $photosetloop['photoset-caption'] .'</figcaption>';
        echo '</figure>';
        }   

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
```

So the loop haves .photoset-item and inside it have image and caption.
My question how to I foreach it, thanks.

I did update for the array, i have group that I loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way it's to make two foreachs, you can do it recursive with a function if you want as well.

```
<?php
$photos =array(
    'photoset-caption' => array(
            'cmb-field-0' => 'Caption1',
            'cmb-field-1' => 'Caption2',
            'cmb-field-2' => 'Caption3',
            'cmb-field-3' => 'Caption4'
     ),
    'photoset-image' => array(
            'cmb-field-0' => 17,
            'cmb-field-1' => 16,
            'cmb-field-2' => 15,
            'cmb-field-3' => 14
    )
);

    foreach($photos as $k => $photo){

        echo '<h1>'.$k.'</h1>';

        foreach($photo as $key => $value){
            echo $key.': '. $value.'<br/>';
        }
        echo '<hr/>';
    }
```

Check an example here:  [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wjozop)

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way to do it, but it does work in this case.

```
$arr = Array
(
    "photoset-caption" => Array
    (
        "cmb-field-0" => "Caption1",
        "cmb-field-1" => "Caption2",
        "cmb-field-2" => "Caption3",
        "cmb-field-3" => "Caption4"
    ),

"photoset-image" => Array
    (
        "cmb-field-0" => 17,
        "cmb-field-1" => 16,
        "cmb-field-2" => 15,
        "cmb-field-3" => 14
    )
);

$count = count($arr["photoset-caption"]);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    echo 'Loop #'.$i.'<br>';
    echo $arr["photoset-caption"]["cmb-field-".$i], '<br>';
    echo $arr["photoset-image"]["cmb-field-".$i], '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

You can paste it here:
http://writecodeonline.com/php/